# Runtime error 1004: Autofill method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofill

Insert a Formula and autofill cells in the adjacent columns

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = shAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 shAll.Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],MCompany,4,FALSE)"
 shAll.Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
```

The code works fine when I step through it using F8 But I get an error when I play it in one go (F5).

Comment: You did not assign the sheet to the destination range.

Comment: Do you also also know that you do not need to autofill. You can enter the formula in the entire range in one go. `shAll.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,MCompany,4,FALSE)"`